# Relationship between binomial and negative binomial probabilities

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial

> Let $X$ be a negative binomial random variable with parameters $r$ and $p$, and let $Y$ be a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$. Show that
> $$
> \mathbb{P}(X > n) = \mathbb{P}(Y < r).
> $$

I would like to get an analytic solution. Basically I want to show the following equality mathematically:
$$
\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \binom{i-1}{r-1} p^r (1-p)^r
 = \sum_{i=0}^{r-1} \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is the minimum number of trials needed to get $r$ successes and $Y$ is the number of successes in $n$ trials. Then it is clear that $Y<r\iff X>n$ from which the result follows.

Comment: i got this but can u prove the equality given in the image

Comment: Since the event $(Y<r)=(X>n)$, it follows that $P(Y<r)=P(X>n)$. Now just remember the pmfs of $Y$ and $X$.

Comment: there is a equality in the image in question can u prove that

Comment: can u prove that without using that the two events are equivalent

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that
$$
1-\sum_{j=r}^n \binom{j-1}{r-1} p^r (1-p)^{j-r}
 = \sum_{j=0}^{r-1} \binom{n}{j} p^j (1-p)^{n-j}
$$
Equivalently
$$
\sum_{j=r}^n \binom{j-1}{r-1}  (1-p)^{j-r}
 =  \sum_{j=r}^{n} \binom{n}{j} p^{j-r} (1-p)^{n-j}
$$
For $n=r$, LHS = 1 = RHS.
Assume the result is true for $n = r + m$, we prove it is true for $n = r + m + 1$. 
LHS =
$$ \sum_{j=r}^{r+m+1} \binom{j-1}{r-1}  (1-p)^{j-r}
 = \sum_{j=r}^{r+m} \binom{j-1}{r-1}  (1-p)^{j-r} +  \binom{r+m}{r-1} (1-p)^{m+1}\\
  =^{(Assumption)}  \sum_{j=r}^{r+m} \binom{r+m}{j} p^{j-r}  (1-p)^{r+m-j} +  \binom{r+m}{r-1} (1-p)^{m+1} \\
=(*) \sum_{j=r}^{r+m} \binom{r+m+1}{j} p^{j-r}  (1-p)^{r+m-j} - \sum_{j=r}^{r+m} \binom{r+m}{j-1} p^{j-r}  (1-p)^{r+m-j} + \binom{r+m}{r-1} (1-p)^{m+1} + p \sum_{j=r}^{r+m} \binom{r+m+1}{j} p^{j-r}  (1-p)^{r+m-j} - p\sum_{j=r}^{r+m} \binom{r+m+1}{j} p^{j-r}  (1-p)^{r+m-j} \\
= \sum_{j=r}^{r+m} \binom{r+m+1}{j} p^{j-r}  (1-p)^{r+m+1-j} + \sum_{j=r}^{r+m} \binom{r+m+1}{j} p^{1+j-r}  (1-p)^{r+m-j} - \sum_{j=r}^{r+m} \binom{r+m}{j-1} p^{j-r}  (1-p)^{r+m-j} + \binom{r+m}{r-1} (1-p)^{m+1} + p^{m+1} - p^{m+1}\\
= \sum_{j=r}^{r+m+1} \binom{r+m+1}{j} p^{j-r}  (1-p)^{r+m+1-j} + A.
$$
Here
$$A = (*) \sum_{j=r}^{r+m} \Bigg\{ \binom{r+m}{j} + \binom{r+m}{j-1}  \Bigg\} p^{1+j-r}  (1-p)^{r+m-j} - \sum_{j=r}^{r+m} \binom{r+m}{j-1} p^{j-r}  (1-p)^{r+m-j} +  \binom{r+m}{r-1}  (1-p)^{m+1} - p^{m+1}\\
 = \sum_{j=r}^{r+m} \binom{r+m}{j} p^{1+j-r}  (1-p)^{r+m-j} - \sum_{j=r}^{r+m} \binom{r+m}{j-1} p^{j-r}  (1-p)^{r+m+1-j} + \binom{r+m}{r-1}  (1-p)^{m+1} - p^{m+1}\\
= \sum_{j=r}^{r+m} \binom{r+m}{j} p^{1+j-r}  (1-p)^{r+m-j}  - \sum_{j'=r-1}^{r+m-1} \binom{r+m}{j'} p^{j'-r+1}  (1-p)^{r+m-j'} + \binom{r+m}{r-1}  (1-p)^{m+1} - p^{m+1} = 0.
 $$
The equalities with $(*)$ make use of [Pascal rule][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Pascal's%20rule%20(or,natural%20numbers%20n%20and%20k%2C&text=is%20a%20binomial%20coefficient%3B%20one,(1%20%2B%20x)n.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Pascal%27s%20rule%20(or,natural%20numbers%20n%20and%20k%2C&text=is%20a%20binomial%20coefficient%3B%20one,(1%20%2B%20x)n.)